# How I can change the incerement value of cloumn

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have a table and have a lot of records and i can't drop and recreate it
I need to change the increment value of the Id column to 2 the old value is 1

this is an example of the table I need to change the identity increment of

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RELATED](
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[RELATEDDESC] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[USER_ID] [int] NULL,
[ALTER_DATE] [datetime2](7) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To specify that the "ID" column should start at value 1 and increment by 2, change it to IDENTITY(1,2).

EDIT*

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[RELATED] 
ALTER COLUMN [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,2) NOT NULL
```

Comment: how to alter existing table that have increment by 1 to become by 2 the alter table fails to do that or I didn't know the correct syntax it gives me error on identity

Comment: ALTER TABLE [dbo].RELATED
ALTER COLUMN [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,20) NOT NULL